# How to fetch username from database through user id after login?

Tags: php, mysql, database, session

login_script.php

```
<?php

require'common.php';

$email = $_POST['e-mail'];
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $email);
$password = $_POST['password'];
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $password);
$password = MD5($password);
// Query checks if the email and password are present in the database.
$query = "SELECT id, email FROM users WHERE email='" . $email . "' AND password='" . $password . "'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query)or die($mysqli_error($con));
$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
// If the email and password are not present in the database, the mysqli_num_rows returns 0, it is assigned to $num.
if ($num == 0) {
  $error = "<span class='red'>Please enter correct E-mail id and Password</span>";
  header('location: login.php?error=' . $error);
} else {  
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
  $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
  header('location: products.php');
}
```

I use session id in login form. Actually I want to fetched user name from user id which is in user table after login.how to fetch that?
Database table: users (id, name, email, mobile, address, city)

Comment: Please provide the basic structure of your table. Your question is not clear.

Comment: one table : users( id,name,email,mobile,address,city)

Comment: actually I want to fetched user name through user id

Comment: Select name from users where id=sessionId will be the sql query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that," users " table contains the field like "username". So, You have to fetch the user record from " users " table by passing the unique-id which is stored in session.

```
    login_script.php 

    <?php

    require'common.php';

    $email = $_POST['e-mail'];
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $email);
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $password);
    $password = MD5($password);
    // Query checks if the email and password are present in the database.
    $query = "SELECT id, email FROM users WHERE email='" . $email . "' AND password='" . $password . "'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query)or trigger_error(mysqli_error());
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    // If the email and password are not present in the database, the mysqli_num_rows returns 0, it is assigned to $num.
    if ($num == 0) {
      $error = "<span class='red'>Please enter correct E-mail id and Password</span>";
      header('location: login.php?error=' . $error);
    } else {  
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
      $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
      $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
      // -------------updated code-------------------
      $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id =". $_SESSION['user_id'];
      $result = mysqli_query($con, $query)or die($mysqli_error($con));
      // your result contains the username value. As per the requirement fetch it
      //------------updated code end-----
      header('location: products.php');
    }
```

Comment: This seems like a very reasonable answer. Just make sure that session is set on your new pages as well so that data would be carried over

Comment: Why a seaerate SQL query when you can get all needed information directly with the first query?

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have replace die with trigger_error() function.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a complete example with prepared statements:

```php
require 'common.php';

// Query checks if the email and password are present in the database.
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT `id`, `name`, `email`, `password` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = ? AND `password` = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['e-mail'], md5($_POST['password']));
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

// If the email and password are not present in the database, the mysqli_num_rows returns 0, it is assigned to $num.
if ($result->num_rows === 0) {
    $error = "<span class='red'>Please enter correct E-mail id and Password</span>";
    header('location: login.php?error=' . $error);
} else {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc());
    $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
    $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
    header('location: products.php');
}
```

Note: Don't use MD5 for hashing the user password, use the password_hash('sha256', PASSWORD_BCRYPT) function to save the password of the user when creating him! MD5 is NOT secure anymore!

Example for user register:

```php
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `email`, `password` VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['name'], $_POST['e-mail'], password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));
...
```

Example for password verify:

```php
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT `id`, `name`, `email` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['e-mail']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

// If the email and password are not present in the database, the mysqli_num_rows returns 0, it is assigned to $num.
if ($result->num_rows === 0) {
    $error = "<span class='red'>Please enter correct E-mail id and Password</span>";
    header('location: login.php?error=' . $error);
    exit;
} else {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc());
    if (!password_verify($_POST['password'], $row['password']) {
        $error = "<span class='red'>Please enter correct E-mail id and Password</span>";
        header('location: login.php?error=' . $error);
        exit;
    }
    $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
    $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
    header('location: products.php');
}
```

Comment: It's already mentioned in my other answer ;) A bit more initiative from the person who need this is also needed ;)

Comment: I've added for usage of password_hash and password_verify :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT id, email FROM users where id='.$_SESSION['user_id'].'";
```

After successful login you need to use your session to retrieve `details(id,email)` from the table.

Comment: this is just for logic you can modify it as per your need and security

Comment: That was my point. Your logic is wrong. You should never put variables into SQL string.

Comment: other person who gave the answer above , his logic and my logic are same , if you see his code above

Comment: No, he uses prepared statements. Completely different answer. See the placeholders instead of PHP variables?

Comment: i am talking about the answer who have 3 point and green check mark

Comment: if you see the question so in question he use core php syntax so my answer is better as respect of that code which ask in question.

Comment: How do you still not understand this. The question was asked with a bug in it. You have then copied the same bug into your code. The solution is not to put `'.$_SESSION['user_id'].'` inside SQL query. Use placeholders and prepared statements. Never concatenate data into SQL. Never escape it or quote it. Only prepared statements are 100% correct solution.

Comment: i understand you and your answer as well but i want to say question is that how to fetch username from database after login so i will give the answer, if you say about sql injection and other security reason so it is whole about other topic

Comment: It is not only about security. It is not whole other topic. It is the same topic.

Comment: please read the REAL answer properly: [How to fetch username from database through user id after login?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56786184/1839439)